# UIWebView not recognizing URL address

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsxmlparser

I've build a XML Parse app,which retrieve from a PHP(XML Content) file some values from my database,in one of those values i have a URL,the problem is,every time i try to load the webView with this URL nothing happens!I have the following code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"users"] ) {

        [messages addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:msgIDEN,@"id",msgAdded,@"added",msgUsername,@"username",msgEmail,@"email",msgMainCode,@"maincode",msgPictureAddress,@"userpictureaddress",nil]];

        [[messages reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        lastId = msgId;

        [msgAdded release];
        [msgUsername release];
        [msgEmail release];
        [msgMainCode release];
        [msgPictureAddress release];

        NSLog(@"UserData:Success");
        NSString *urlAddress = msgPictureAddress;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webViewMateus loadRequest:requestObj];


    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"id"] )                  { inIDEN = NO;  }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"username"] )            { inUsername = NO;  }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"email"] )               { inEmail = NO;  }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"usermaincode"] )        { inMainCode = NO;  }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"userpictureaddress"] )  { inPictureAddress = NO;  }

}
```

How can i make the UIWebView address become the same as my `NSMutableString = userpictureaddress`?

Comment: Why can't you just initialize the UIWEBView after parsing?

Comment: Also consider that using `UIWebView` for displaying just a single image, may be an overkill, there are solutions on the net for asynchronous image downloading and displaying (like https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). In addition to control the caching by yourself you'll get ability to set placeholder image to display while image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code, you just threw away (released) your msgPictureAddress before you assigned it to urlAddress.  Are you sure you want to be releasing that stuff at that time?